# Deserialize an object in RabbitMQ

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

I have an object I'm sending on a queue that is an object. I have another queue that reads that queue. I can read the data from that queue in the form of a string but I want to deserialize it as the object I sent.

I've tried to format it a few ways and cast the message string received as the object but its not correct.

```
    Console.WriteLine("Listening for messages");

            _model.BasicQos(0, 1, false);
            Subscription _subscription = new Subscription(_model, QueueName, false);

            while (true)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(2000);

                //Get next message
                var deliveryArgs = _subscription.Next();

                //Deserialize message
                var message = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(deliveryArgs.Body);

                var t = (MyMessageObject)_subscription.Queue.Dequeue().Body.Deserialize(typeof(MyMessageObject));
                var t2 = (MyMessageObject)deliveryArgs.Body.Deserialize(typeof(MyMessageObject));

                Console.WriteLine("<=== Received {0} {1}", t.myId, t.myAmount);

                //Acknowledge message is processed
                _subscription.Ack(deliveryArgs);
```

Comment: You need to read up on various methods to serialize and deserialize data. Once you've done that, please explain the precise problem you are having.

Comment: I did a little research and was able to find a solution below.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:
var message = (object)deliveryArgs.Body.DeSerialize(typeof(object));

Just need to cast to what ever your object is.